# Sylius, specific product price per customer group

Tags: sylius

I would need to define specific prices for each customer group.

But not per channel.

How can I do this from the Back-Office?

Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solutoin ?

Comment: nope, for the moment it is only a specific development.